# How to search for specific file type in Firefox history?

Tags: firefox, history

E.g. you'd think to search for `*.pdf` if you want to find a PDF in Firefox history, but this brings up nothing. So what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are searching for `*.pdf` - ie try `.pdf`!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the [Places database](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite) that can be queried with industrial [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/). For instance, I have got all my PDF files with SQ

```
SELECT * FROM moz_places where url like '%.pdf'
```

Comment: Note that firefox removes downloads from the history older than 60days (ref: https://superuser.com/a/1405880/153095)